# django_tables2 pagination and sorting don't work

Tags: django, sorting, django-tables2, django-pagination

I'm using django_talbes2 and the table renders correctly (in a sense that it displays all the information it should), but when I click on a column header to sort it or on a page number to go to the next page it "breaks" -- it returns to the home page and I'm not on the view which renders the table anymore.

Actually, the problem is VERY SIMILAR to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499220/django-tables2-header-row-urls-wrong-cant-sort)

But the accepted solution wouldn't work in my case because I'm not using any `<base>` tags, which were causing the problem there.

This is my table:

```
class FactTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Fact
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        exclude = ('id',)
```

This is my view:

```
def results(request, fields):

     table = FactTable(Fact.objects.filter(category__category=fields['category'],
                                          fact_name=fields['fact'],
                                          time_year__year__range=(startyear, endyear)))

     RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
     return render(request, 'main/results.html', {'table': table})
```

My urls:

```
 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
     url(r'^results/', views.results, name='results'),
 ]
```

And the template

```
 {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <title>Results</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     {% render_table table %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Ok read this --->>> https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/filtering.html#filtering   and ------>>>> https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-headers-and-footers.html#column-headers-and-footers  and this ----->>>> https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pinned-rows.html#pinned-rows